# How do I test httpd.conf on my Windows?

Tags: windows, apache2.4

Different websites give me different answers to this question, but I think they area all for linux. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apachectl.html gives me a useful tool, but this cannot be used on my command prompt (picture below).

[image: problem]

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On windows, test the configuration with:

```
httpd.exe -t
```

Comment: Can't find a file for V7 ,inside bin directory.

Comment: I don't know what "V7" means here, but the question is about Apache 2.4 on Windows.